# Dynamically traverse an object of unknown depth's keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, javascript-objects

I have kind of a strange question -- possibly a stupid question -- that requires some explanation, so please bear with me. Basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to traverse an object of unknown depth in JavaScript without using recursion.

For example, let's say I have an object of unknown depth. It can look like this:

```
let obj_depth2 = {
  male:
    { short: 0, tall: 0 },
  female:
    { short: 0, tall: 0 }
  }
```

or maybe like this:

```
let obj_depth3 = {
  male: {
    short:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 },
    tall:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 }
  },
  female: {
    short:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 },
    tall:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 }
  }
}
```

The `obj` may be deeper as well. I will not know its depth ahead of time.

Let's assume further that I will have an `arr` that looks something like this, and will match the depth of the `obj` in length.

```
let arr_depth2 = ["male", "short"];
```

or

```
let arr_depth3 = ["male", "tall", "basketball"];
```

I will have a loop in which I generate, say, 1,000, of these `arr`s that I will then use to add `1` to the `obj` of unknown depth. All the `arr`s will be the same length (2 or 3, or more) and will always match the depth of the `obj`. But the depth will change and I want to write a single function to cover all situations.

To be clear, I will NOT have a situation where I have an `obj` of depth 2 and an `arr` of length 3. The depths and lengths will always match for all 1,000 iterations at a time.

My question is this. Is there a way to traverse the `obj` to add `1` to the value of the "deepest" key-value pair I need to reach without using recursion?

Can I build something like this?

```
obj["male"]["short"] += 1;
```

Although I know I can use recursion to reach the bottom depth of the `obj`, add `1` to the proper `value`, and `return` it, rebuilding the `obj` as the recursive function continues to `return`, this means I would have to rebuild the `obj` for every single value every time and override the `obj` I would have just built on the previous iteration, just to add `1` to one part of the `obj`. It just *seems* bad, but maybe it doesn't matter.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to modify the object in place, you can essentially use a pointer to traverse the object to the point you get to the last key and then set it.

```js
const obj_depth3 = {
  male: {
    short:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 },
    tall:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 }
  },
  female: {
    short:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 },
    tall:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 }
  }
}

const addOneTo = (obj, path) => {
  const finalProp = path.pop();
  const pointer = path.reduce((pointer, key) => pointer[key], obj);
  pointer[finalProp]++;
}

addOneTo(obj_depth3, ["male", "short", "soccer"])

console.log(obj_depth3);
```

Comment: Reduce! Eureka! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `.reduce()` to traverse down your object, where the accumulator keeps track of your current object in your traversal. When your reduce is complete, it will have the inner-most nested object in your path, which you can then use the last element in your array as a key to modify the value. As you said, there is no need for recursion if you're happy with simply mutating the original object:

```js
const obj = {male:{short:{basketball:0,soccer:0},tall:{basketball:0,soccer:0}},female:{short:{basketball:0,soccer:0},tall:{basketball:0,soccer:0}}}
const arr = ["male", "tall", "basketball"];

const modify = (obj, [...keys]) => {
  const last_key = keys.pop();        
  const last_obj = keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k], obj);
  last_obj[last_key] += 1;
}

modify(obj, arr);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can safely access a nested object in your described case using the reduce function:

```
const getNestedObject = (nestedObj, pathArr) => {
    return pathArr.reduce((obj, key) =>
        (obj && obj[key] !== 'undefined') ? obj[key] : undefined, nestedObj);
}
```

Then you can access your desired ['male']['short'] object in a similar fashion:

```
let shortMale = getNestedObject(obj_depth3, ['male', 'short'])
```

And you can perform your desired operation on the object:

```
shortMale.basketball += 1
```

For more information on the getNestedObject function, see: https://hackernoon.com/accessing-nested-objects-in-javascript-f02f1bd6387f

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula to get all parts of an unknown sized thing once u can call the folder name in JavaScript
`Object.entries(yourObject)`
This returns an array of all the data of your object so you can easily iterate through it. I would return your data in the example to show you how the Object.entries works

```js
const obj_depth3 = {
  male: {
    short:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 },
    tall:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 }
  },
  female: {
    short:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 },
    tall:
      { basketball: 0, soccer: 0 }
  }
}
console.log(Object.entries(obj_depth3));
//you might still want to use another console like inspect element's own to see how the array works, but it has all the depth and stuff :)
```